# Creating 2 versions of same lib using GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to create 2 different versions of same lib (.a & .so files), using different compilation flags.
for instance,
the following debug flag should be enabled in only one of the builds:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_NEW_FEATURE
//some code
#endif
```

the lib Makefile is being called from outside project with many executables, some of them need to have the new feature and some of them not.
i wonder how can i use Makefile to create 2 different versions of same lib without suffering race condition in case of running `make -j`.

Comment: The usual way is to write the output from compiling with each set of flags to a different directory so they don't interfere with each other.  Then there will be no issue with running builds in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to use several directories for the objects.  Then you may use something like:

```
SOURCES=f1.cpp f2.cpp

all: libmylib-d.a libmylib-o.so

libmylib-d.a: CFLAGS=-Dd
libmylib-d.a: $(SOURCES:%.cpp=obj-d/%.o)
    ar -cru $@ $^

libmylib-o.so: CFLAGS=-Do -fPIC
libmylib-o.so: $(SOURCES:%.cpp=obj-o/%.o)
    g++ -shared -o $@ $^

obj-d/%.o: %.cpp | obj-d
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

obj-o/%.o: %.cpp | obj-o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

obj-o obj-d:
    mkdir $@
```